# What is the correct way to have a click event fire on Button with a Border

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, border

I've added some styling to an application's buttons and now the click event only fires if you click on the text of the button (because it fires the TextBox click event which bubbles up).

Here's the Snoop trace of two clicks on the button. The first click was inside the button but outside the text area.  The second click fired the event to show the *Click detected* MessageBox:

[image]

app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="88.298" Width="223.936">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="ClickMe" Width="70" Margin="0,0,30,0" Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButton}" Click="ClickMe_Click">Click Me</Button>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click detected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a non transparent (or near to transparent) background for the Border in the Template of the button.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed Border in app.xaml:

<Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2" Background="#01010101">

Now I've just got to figure out why this made it work :)

Thanks again.

Comment: It works because if your control is transparent, it is "filled with air". So your click crosses your component